# Smartgwt - исчезает содержимое Layout после повторного открытия Tab в TabSet

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

Возникла проблема - при навигации в основном окне открываются вкладки в TabSet. и если вкладку закрыть, то ее можно открыть снова. проблема в том, что если вкладку, которая extends VLayout, закрыть и открыть снова - элемент отказывается пустым и в консоли видно, что у этого лэйаута просто нет содержимого.
Вот класс:

```
public class PrintWidget extends VLayout {
private static PrintWidget instance = null;
private static DataSource widgetData = null;
private String widgetName = null;

public static PrintWidget getInstance() {
    if (widgetData == null) {
        widgetData = ListData.getInstance();
    }
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new PrintWidget("PrintWidgetPresentation");
    }
    return instance;
}

public PrintWidget(String widgetName) {
    this.widgetName = widgetName;

    SectionStack printStack = new SectionStack();
    printStack.setVisibilityMode(VisibilityMode.MULTIPLE);
    printStack.setWidth(400);
    printStack.setHeight("85%");

    final DetailViewer printViewer = new DetailViewer();
    printViewer.setDataSource(widgetData);
    printViewer.setHeight("40%");
    printViewer.setMargin(10);
    printViewer.setEmptyMessage("Выберете запись из списка для отображения деталей.");

    final ListGrid printGrid = new ListGrid();
    printGrid.setDataSource(widgetData);
    printGrid.setHeight("60%");
    printGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);
    printGrid.setGroupByField("bookAuthor");

    ListGridField bookAuthorField = new ListGridField("bookAuthor", "Автор");
    ListGridField bookTitleField = new ListGridField("bookTitle", "Название");
    printGrid.setFields(bookAuthorField, bookTitleField);


    final SectionStackSection listDataSection = new SectionStackSection("Записи");
    listDataSection.setExpanded(true);
    listDataSection.addItem(printGrid);
    printStack.addSection(listDataSection);

    final SectionStackSection detailsSection = new SectionStackSection("Детализированное представление записи");
    detailsSection.setExpanded(false);
    VStack vStack = new VStack();
    vStack.setOverflow(Overflow.AUTO);
    vStack.setWidth100();
    vStack.addMember(printViewer);
    detailsSection.addItem(vStack);
    printStack.addSection(detailsSection);

    printGrid.addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler() {
        public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event) {
            printViewer.setData(new Record[]{event.getRecord()});
            detailsSection.setExpanded(true);
        }
    });

    setHeight("85%");
    addMembers(printGrid, printViewer);
}
```

А вот так создается вкладка в TabSet

```
    Tab newTab = new Tab(event.getNode().getTitle());
    newTab.setID("PrintTab");
    newTab.setCanClose(true);

    final PrintWidget printTabContent = PrintWidget.getInstance();

    newTab.setPane(printTabContent);
```

А вот так добавляется на основную панель:

```
if (newTab != null) {
   tabsPane.addTab(newTab);
   tabsPane.selectTab(newTab);
} else SC.say("К сожалению нет отображения, соответствующего этому элементу.");
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять в чем дело, почему содержание не создается при повторном вызове?